# ASPXNAVBAR get selected navbar item name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have here a ASPxNavbar I want to get the NavBar item name every time I clicked on the navbar items and display it on a label. I tried doing it in JavaScript but nothing seem to works.

Here is what I tried so far

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" Text="ASPxLabel">
        </dx:ASPxLabel>

<dx:ASPxNavBar ID="ASPxNavBar1" runat="server" EnableAnimation="True" Width="100%" 
        Theme="Material" AllowSelectItem="true" Target="contentUrlPane" ClientInstanceName="NavbarClick">
    <LinkStyle>
        <HoverFont Underline="False" />
    </LinkStyle>    
    <Border BorderWidth="0px" />
    <Paddings Padding="0px" />
    <GroupHeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />

    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left">
    <SelectedStyle BackColor="#404652 " ForeColor="#a2a2a2" />
    </ItemStyle>

<ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function NavbarClick(s, e) {
 ave  = e.item.name;
alert(ave)
document.getElementById('ASPxLabel1').innerHTML = ave;
}"/>
    <Groups>
    <dx:NavBarGroup Text="DASHBOARD" ></dx:NavBarGroup>
    <dx:NavBarGroup Text="Forms">
        <Items>
        <dx:NavBarItem Text="Cancel Memo" NavigateUrl="sample.aspx" Selected="True" Name = "Sample Title Here">
            <Image Height="18px" Url="Content/Images/1.png" Width="18px"  />
        </dx:NavBarItem>
        <dx:NavBarItem Text="Change Memo" NavigateUrl="Sample2.aspx" Name = "Another sample title here">
            <Image Height="18px" Url="Content/Images/2.png" Width="18px" />
        </dx:NavBarItem>
        </Items>
    </dx:NavBarGroup>
   </Groups>
   </dx:ASPxNavBar>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Correct the client-side [ItemClick](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/NavBar/ClientSide.aspx) function assignment as follows:

```
<ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function(s, e) {
    ave  = e.item.name;
    alert(ave);
}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
protected void FiltersNavBar_ItemClick(object source, NavBarItemEventArgs e)
{
   var strValue = e.Item.Name;
   if (strValue == "New")
   {
   }
}
```